# how to use wait_for in c++0x thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

On gcc 4.4.6, RHEL 6.3 linux, i see the template in thread header

```
template<typename _Rep, typename _Period>
  inline void
  sleep_for(const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& __rtime)
```

But if i try to use it in my application, i get error that `sleep_for is not a member of std::this_thread`

My application is simple as

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When compiling add this parameter to your command line:

```
-D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP
```

So compile like this:

```
gcc -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP test.cpp -o test
```

if using g++ you can use

```
g++ -std=gnu++0x -pthread test.cpp -o test
```

Comment: if you need, feel free to add

Comment: @Jimm In case of using gnu++0x you theoretically shouldn't, but AFAIK it's still not auto-linked on Linux.